# Windows Forms - Populate existing datagridview with new data without erasing existing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a piece of code below which on the click of a button will promt the user to select a .csv file from their storeage. After this the file will populate the the datagridview with its contents.

```
     public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string delimiter = ",";
            string tablename = "AudioTable";
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;


            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " + openFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
                    string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    dataset.Tables.Add(tablename);
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("QID");
                    dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Text");
;

                    string allData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] rows = allData.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

                    foreach (string r in rows)
                    {
                        string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Rows.Add(items);
                    }
                    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    MessageBox.Show(filename + " was successfully imported.", "Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }

            }
        }
```

This code runs fine by consistantly displaying the data within the datagridview however, When you attempt to upload a second different .csv this files data will overwrite the existing data from the 1st .csv. Is there any possible way to change this so that instead of overwriting the existing data within the datagridview it will just append it into new rows below the existing data. To try and make it abit clearer, The first time user uploads a .csv there is no existing data within the datagridview so it loads fine but if that same user wants to upload second .csv after the first thats when the existing data from the 1st .csv will be overwritten. I have searched about and seen a few issues similar to this relating to datatables in web based solutions however was unsure how translate there to suit my own.

Thanks

Comment: Don't create a new dataset every time, just add to one you keep in memory.

Answer (score 1):

each time you try do this you use the same dataset , and create a new on the previous. that's why the data is overwritten

save the contents of what you want to add to the datagridview data source into a data table, and then merge them together into datagridview datasource

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 

// fill your table 

(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Merge(dt2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add more columns to your dataset and then call this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView; again.